# How to improve this component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this Component that calls 3rd party joke api when page load with particular category, Inside
this added refresh button to get new joke,

```
export default function Jokes() {
const { cat } = useParams();
const [joke, setJoke] = useState({
 joke: "",
});

const api = useApi(); // use context for the api

useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  const response = await api.getJokes(cat);
  if (response.ok) {
    const { body:joke } = response;
    setJoke((prev) => ({ ...prev, joke }));
  } else {
    setJoke(null);
  }
})();
}, [cat]);

const refresh = async (e) => {
const response = await api.getJokes(cat);
  if (response.ok) {
    const { body:joke } = response;
    setJoke((prev) => ({ ...prev, joke }));
  } else {
    setJoke(null);
  }
};

if (joke.joke === "") {
return <Spinner animation="border" />;
}

return (
<Container>
  {joke.joke !== "" ? (
    <Body>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>{joke.joke}</Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <Button style={{ marginTop: "20px" }} onClick={refresh}>
        Load New
      </Button>
    </Body>
  ) : (
    <Spinner animation="border" />
  )}
</Container>
);
```

}

My question is how to improve this code to remove 2nd api request when user click on Load new button

Comment: If you can get all the data in one hit (in your case all the jokes) store them and when the user clicks load new then change the joke from the declared variable to the next joke. This will reduce the call of the API to 1

Comment: @Nikhil it only allow one response for each request

Comment: If the API itself allows one response at a time then there is nothing we can do about it. If you need a new joke you will have to hit it for the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, extract the logic of fetching the joke into a method and call it when required.

```
export default function Jokes() {
  const { cat } = useParams();
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState({
    joke: "",
  });

  const api = useApi(); // use context for the api

  useEffect(() => {
    (await fetchJoke())();
  }, [cat]);

  const fetchJoke = async (e) => {
    const response = await api.getJokes(cat);
    if (response.ok) {
      const { body: joke } = response;
      setJoke((prev) => ({ ...prev, joke }));
    } else {
      setJoke(null);
    }
  };

  if (joke.joke === "") {
    return <Spinner animation="border" />;
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      {joke.joke !== "" ? (
        <Body>
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>{joke.joke}</Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <Button style={{ marginTop: "20px" }} onClick={fetchJoke}>
            Load New
      </Button>
        </Body>
      ) : (
          <Spinner animation="border" />
        )}
    </Container>
  );
}
```